# Forcing prefix on all xml elements in xml document

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have checked and tried multiple solutions to this problem and still can't get this working.

I create an XML file from a dataset (filled from an Excel file). The file works fine and I have validated it against the XSD. The only issue I have remaining is that the namespace prefix I defined in the root element does not appear in any of the elements in the XMLDocument. Here is the code that generates the XMLDocument (NOTE - partDS is the dataset from which the XML file was loaded):

```vb
Private Sub WriteXML_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Writer.Click
    Dim fName As String = "C:\Users\ThisUser\Desktop\Plain.xml"

    partDS.DataSetName = "XMLDataDelivery"
    partDS.WriteXml(fName)

    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument

    Dim schemaLocation As XmlAttribute = Nothing
    Dim schemaString As String = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    Dim schemaValue As String = "http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001 7143706-001RevA.xsd"

    Dim namespaceAttribute As XmlAttribute = Nothing
    Dim nsString As String = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/"
    Dim nsValue As String = "http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001"

    Dim commonTimeElement As XmlElement = Nothing
    Dim commonTimeAttribute As XmlAttribute = Nothing
    Dim commonTimeString As String = "/XMLDataDelivery/CommonHeader/SubmittedDateTimeUTC"

    Dim dataTimeElement As XmlElement = Nothing
    Dim dataTimeAttribute As XmlAttribute = Nothing
    Dim dataTimeString As String = "/XMLDataDelivery/Data/LogisticsEvent/DateTime"

    Dim timeAttributeString = "dl:DateTime12HourWithoutFeb29"

    Dim dateTimeNodeList As XmlNodeList = Nothing
    Dim parentLevels As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/XMLDataDelivery/Data/LogisticsEvent")
    Dim higherLevels As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/XMLDataDelivery/Data/LogisticsEvent/Activity")
    Dim partLevels As XmlNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/XMLDataDelivery/Data/LogisticsEvent/AssemblyItem")

    xDoc.Load(fName)

    'define XML namespace and attributes in XML header
    namespaceAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xmlns", "dl", nsString)
    namespaceAttribute.Value = nsValue
    xDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes.Append(namespaceAttribute)

    schemaLocation = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", schemaString)
    schemaLocation.Value = schemaValue
    xDoc.DocumentElement.SetAttributeNode(schemaLocation)

    'define and set attributes for the dateTime elements in the XML
    commonTimeElement = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(commonTimeString)
    commonTimeAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "type", schemaString)
    commonTimeAttribute.Value = timeAttributeString
    commonTimeElement.SetAttributeNode(commonTimeAttribute)

    dataTimeAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "type", schemaString)
    dataTimeAttribute.Value = timeAttributeString

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do Until i > parentLevels.Count - 1
        parentLevels.ItemOf(i).InsertBefore(partLevels.ItemOf(i), higherLevels.ItemOf(i))
        i += 1
    Loop

    dateTimeNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/XMLDataDelivery/Data/LogisticsEvent/DateTime")
    For Each item As XmlElement In dateTimeNodeList
        item.SetAttribute("type", schemaString, timeAttributeString)
    Next

    xDoc.Save(fName)

End Sub
```

Which generates XML similar to below:

```
<XMLDataDelivery xmlns:dl="http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001 7143706-001RevA.xsd">
  <Data>
    <Location>Site01</Location>
    <LogisticsEvent>
      <DateTime>01-JUL-2015 12:00:00 PM</DateTime>
      <AssemblyItem>
        <ProductName>Test Part1</ProductName>
        <ProductNumber>998741</ProductNumber>
        <ProductDash>050</ProductDash>
        <SerialNumber>LX2247</SerialNumber>
        <ProductRevision>R</ProductRevision>
      </AssemblyItem>
      <Activity>Stat Change</Activity>
      <Condition>Good</Condition>
      <Usage>Production</Usage>
    <LogisticsEvent>
  </Data>
</XMLDataDelivery>
```

Now from what I remember from my research (still new to programming XML in vb.net), if the namespace is defined in the root, then the prefix for the same namespace does not need to (or will not?) appear on each node in the XMLDocument.

While I agree with this (and my validator agrees this is a valid XML file), the system to which these files will be uploaded will fail the validation if the prefix is not appended to each of the nodes.

I have tried multiple fixes from simply defining the root prefix (xDoc.DocumentElement.prefix = "dl") to trying different attribute settings, using namespacemanager and have still not gotten anything to stick.

The XML file is created from scratch (not loaded from any template). I did try the command xDoc.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("dl") but that did not return anything.

Sorry this is long, but just wanted to make sure I had enough info. Thanks to anyone who reviews this.

Comment: You can not change the [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.namespaceuri(v=vs.110).aspx) of an element after it is created.  You need to recreate the element with the [proper namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929969/add-a-xmlnode-with-the-namespace-of-the-parent-node-in-net)

Comment: I added the namespace and prefix to the dataset before it is written to the XML `partds.Namespace = "http://www.tgin...etc" partds.prefix = "dl"`. The prefix appears on the root element and the namespace appears on the parent nodes (CommonHeader, DataHeader & Data), however the prefix does not appear with any element other than the root element. Also, after loading the xml doc I tried the command `xdoc.GetNamespaceofPrefix("dl")` and it still did not return anything. I feel like I missing something basic here...

Comment: I added the "dl" prefix to each of tables in the partds dataset. Now the prefix shows on all the parent nodes and the namespace `xmlns="http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001"` appears on all the child nodes. I guess I'm almost there...?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't realize what Sam Axe meant (would upvote your comment if I could) until I delved a bit further. In the end, I didn't realize I could change the prefix of the data columns in the data set to associate with the namespace declared in the root:

```
    partDS.Tables("CommonHeader").Prefix = "dl"
    partDS.Tables("DataHeader").Prefix = "dl"
    partDS.Tables("Data").Prefix = "dl"
    partDS.Tables("LogisticsEvent").Prefix = "dl"
    partDS.Tables("AssemblyItem").Prefix = "dl"

    Dim logCol As Integer = 0
    Dim assyCol As Integer = 0

    Do Until logCol > partDS.Tables("LogisticsEvent").Columns.Count - 1
        partDS.Tables("LogisticsEvent").Columns(logCol).Prefix = "dl"
        logCol += 1
    Loop

    Do Until assyCol > partDS.Tables("AssemblyItem").Columns.Count - 1
        partDS.Tables("AssemblyItem").Columns(assyCol).Prefix = "dl"
        assyCol += 1
    Loop

    partDS.DataSetName = "XMLDataDelivery"
    partDS.Namespace = "http://www.tgin.org/trident/7143706-001"
    partDS.Prefix = "dl"
```

Thanks very much for the help.